# Conditional shift within array with Jolt

Tags: json, transform, jolt

Thanks in advance for reading this one!

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "transactions": [
    {
      "type": "wd",
      "charged": "-1000.00",
      "credited": "0"
    },
    {
      "type": "dep",
      "charged": "0",
      "credited": "1000.00"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I need is to keep either charged or credited, whichever one is not 0.  My spec below almost has it working

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "transactions": {
        "*": {
          "type": "settled.[&1].transType",
          "charged": {
            "0": {
              "@(2,credited)": "settled.[&1].cash_movement"
            }
          },
          "credited": {
            "0": {
              "@(2,charged)": "settled.[&1].cash_movement"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

What I want to end up with is:

```json
{
  "settled": [
    {
      "transType": "wd",
      "cash_movement": "-1000.00"
    },
    {
      "transType": "dep",
      "cash_movement": "1000.00"
    }
  ]
}
```

But what I end up with is this instead:

```json
{
  "settled": [
    {
      "transType": "wd",
      "cash_movement": ["-1000.00","1000.00"]
    },
    {
      "transType": "dep"
    }
  ]
}
```

I know I'm close but for the life of me, I haven't been able to tweak it to get it just right.  Can someone set me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to convert the identifiers `[&1]` to `[&3]` except for the first one such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "transactions": {
        "*": {
          "type": "settled[&1].transType",
          "charged": {
            "0": {
              "@(2,credited)": "settled[&3].cash_movement"
            }
          },
          "credited": {
            "0": {
              "@(2,charged)": "settled[&3].cash_movement"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

since twice more going the tree up needed for those innermost pairs in order to reach the same level with the first `[&1]`. Btw, the dots between `settled` and `[&.]`s are redundant to be used.

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  It makes sense now that I see it but I just wasn't realizing that I was two steps further down the tree.  Works perfectly!!

Comment: welcome to SO @CarolSerroul , best wishes.